# Automate php and mySQL queries by time

Tags: php, mysql

How can I run a php file or execute a mySQL query automatically depending on the time? For example, by 12mn I want my server to automatically run *somefile.php.*

**More:** I have a LAMP setup.

Comment: In unix, you can try use [Cron](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab). Other suggestion is create a `.txt` file that store last execution time, but is need too many visits, or a "`infinite while`" (server need support)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [Cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). you can schedule the PHP file to be executed with the cron and cron will take care of rest.

If you are on LAMP platform, check out [how to setup cron](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just read something about `cronjobs`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Cron :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

ex :

```
* */12 * * * php /cron/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to setup a cron job (or if you can't) you can use a service like [WebBasedCron](http://webbasedcron.com)